# Neo4j Client Creating Relationship between two existing Nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I have tried to create a relationship between two nodes while using Unwind on existing relationships (I am trying to migrate from a previous database)

So Links = relationships which hold the Id of each node on target and source (ID is different from the neo4j id)

The Cypher does not return any error and I do manage to add the nodes but for some reason that I cannot understand why the relationships between nodes are not getting created.

I am using this Cypher:

```
graphClient.Cypher
    .Unwind(graph.Links, "singleLink")
    .Match("(firstNode:Node{id: singleLink.Source , projectId: {innerProjectId}})", "(secondNode:Node{id: singleLink.Target , project: {innerProjectId}})")
    .WithParam("innerProjectId",project.Id)
    .Create("(firstNode:Node)-[:ConnectedTo{source: singleLink.Source, target: singleLink.Target}]->(secondNode:Node)")
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Regarding "I do manage to add the nodes": the code you provided would never attempt to create any nodes, since the `CREATE` clause would only be executed if the `MATCH` clause had already found the nodes. Are you sure you have existing `Node` nodes with the specified `id` AND `projectId` values?

Comment: Yes. I am sure of it

Comment: What does the `DebugQueryText` look like?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is wat you want;

```
MATCH (n1), (n2)
WHERE ID(n1) = 1 AND ID(n2) = 2
CREATE (n1)-[r:RELATION]->(n2)
```

Comment: I need the cypher on a .NET Client Cypher , and I am not using the Neo4j ID (Its a bad practice) so the ID(n) is not good for me , the Id I put inside is ID generated from SQL .

Comment: You can test it in the Neo4j browser self? 

`MATCH (n1{Id:1}), (n2{Id:2})
CREATE (n1)-[r:RELATION]->(n2)`

Comment: In the browser the cypher I am writing is working thats why its so weird to me .. I really think that the cypher I wrote is good and should work. I do a match with 2 parameters not only ID but another parameter aswell btw

Comment: Ok, i dont now anything about the .NET Client. Maybe you can join the Neo4j slack and ask there that somebody can view this question on Stackoverflow.